# Undo "No border" in KDE

Tags: kde

I alt-clicked on a window's title bar and removed the bar by clicking "No border" but now I have no accessible means to restore that window's title bar. Is there a way to open KWin for that specific window? What are my options for restoring the window's border? (Plasma 5, if it's version-specific.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check in `Systemsettings > Application Style > Window Decorations`

there should be an option to set borders.

or edit the following config file: `~/.config/kwinrc`

look for the line: `BorderlessMaximizedWindows=true`

and either change it to false or comment it out.

Comment: Neither of these apply to me. I'm also on Plasma 5. There's no option to set borders, and the line in kwinrc already doesn't exist.

Comment: this setting is non-existent in Plasma 5

Comment: I can clearly hear the voice of a colleague now, he's always around when there's a problem with linux that requires this kind of solution, while in another OS you just press a button. 
Luckily I've solved with Janghou's answer...and his voice went away :-D

Answer (score 23):

Focus window:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> ⇒ "more actions" ⇒ uncheck "no border"

Answer (score 3):

press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> on window with focus:

choose menu item(s): more actions > [deselect] 'no borders'

You should get a message dialog when you 'hide border' that reads something like ... blah, blah. use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to show menu
allowing you to do the above with your mouse.

If you are Not getting the message do this (utf-8 editor!):
Edit file: `~/.kde4(.kde)/share/config/kwin_dialogsrc`
Change or Add the Line(s):

```
[Notification Messages]
altf3warning=true
```

Save, Done. (no restart necessary)

Comment: The first half of your answer duplicates [Janghou’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/376091/23408#470365).

Comment: so what.
It's a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing, but I didn't find anything relevant in `~/.config/kwinrc`.

I found the application-specific settings in `~/.config/kwinrulesrc`.  I removed them with Vim, and restarted kwin_x11, and restored the border on the program I had previously removed the border from.